# MIT license alternative with explicit trademark use protection

Tags: mit, license-recommendation, license-notice, license, mpl

Do you know a license, if possible approved by the [Open Source Initiative](https://opensource.org/), that's very similar to the MIT license but has explicit trademark use protection like the MLP 2.0 license?

[image: MLP 2.0 license on GH]

Comment: What do you mean by "very similar"? The Apache License has many more words but is a permissive license with trademark protection.